# charts not renderring in django-nvd3

Tags: django, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am trying to use django-nvd3 with my django project, and am trying to get the line-chart example working. I get the following errors in the chrome js console when my page loads:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'monthEnd' of undefined
>   nv.d3.js:115 (anonymous function) nv.d3.js:115 (anonymous function)
>   nv.d3.js:14369 Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method
>   'lineChart' (index):13 (anonymous function) (index):13 (anonymous
>   function) nv.d3.js:63

I have basically copied the code from here:
http://django-nvd3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/classes-doc/line-chart.html

my view is:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, render
import random
import datetime
import time

def demo_linechart(request):
    """
    lineChart page
    """
    start_time = int(time.mktime(datetime.datetime(2012, 6, 1).timetuple()) * 1000)
    nb_element = 100
    xdata = range(nb_element)
    xdata = map(lambda x: start_time + x * 1000000000, xdata)
    ydata = [i + random.randint(1, 10) for i in range(nb_element)]
    ydata2 = map(lambda x: x * 2, ydata)

    tooltip_date = "%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %p"
    extra_serie = {"tooltip": {"y_start": "", "y_end": " cal"},
                   "date_format": tooltip_date}
    chartdata = {'x': xdata,
                 'name1': 'series 1', 'y1': ydata, 'extra1': extra_serie,
                 'name2': 'series 2', 'y2': ydata2, 'extra2': extra_serie}
    charttype = "lineChart"

    kw_extra = {
        'x_is_date': True,
        'x_axis_format':"%d %b %Y",
    }

    data = {
        'charttype': charttype,
        'chartdata': chartdata,
        'kw_extra':kw_extra,
    }
    return render(request, 'smcore/nvd3.html', data)
```

my html is:

```
{% load static %}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'nvd3/nv.d3.css' %}" />
<script type="text/javascript" src='{% static 'smcore/jquery-latest.js' %}'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='{% static 'smcore/d3.min.js' %}'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='{% static 'nvd3/nv.d3.js' %}'></script>

{% load nvd3_tags %}
<head>
    {% load_chart charttype chartdata "linechart_container" kw_extra %}

    {#    {% load_chart charttype chartdata "linechart_container" True '%d %b %Y %H' %}#}
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Fruits vs Calories</h1>
    {#    {% include_container "piechart_container" 400 500 %}#}
    {% include_container "linechart_container" 400 600 %}

</body>
```

my url is:

```
url(r'testvis/$', temp.demo_linechart, name='testvis'),
```

I am using 
nv.version = '1.1.15b'; 
d3 = {version: "2.7.0"}; // semver

please help!!

Answer (score 2):

For me, the solution was in the first comment from `samesense` here:

https://github.com/areski/django-nvd3/issues/24

Namely:

> ```
> data = {
>     'charttype': charttype,
>     'chartdata': chartdata,
>     'extra': {'x_is_date': True,
>     'x_axis_format': "%d %b %Y %H"},
>   }
> Then you fix the template to make it look like the piechart example.
> Change
> {% load_chart charttype chartdata "linechart_container" True "%d %b %Y %H" %}
> to
> {% load_chart charttype chartdata "linechart_container" extra %}
> ```